# Remove strings of a filename and leave others in BASH

Tags: bash, filenames

I have a lot of files like this:

```
2007.365.00.00.00.0000.9A.CVSV4..HHZ.D.SAC.GAP.decim10.GAP
```

In the end I want it like:

```
2007.365.00.00.CVSV4.HHZ.SAC
```

I tried this:

```
for file in /home/joana/Desktop/*GAP; do
mv "$file" `echo "$file" | sed -e 's/00.0000.9A.//' -e 's/.D//' -e 's/.GAP.decim10.GAP//'`;
done
```

Anda I get this:

```
mv: cannot move ‘/home/joana/Desktop/2007.365.00.00.00.0000.9A.CVSV4..HHZ.D.SAC.GAP.decim10.GAP’ to ‘/home/joanaesktop/2007.365.00.00.CVSV4..HHZ.D.SAC’: No such file or directory
```

Anyone can help me? I saw a lot of examples but I am probably doing something wrong.

Comment: Renaming based on what?

Comment: your send command removes the D in Desktop also

/home/joanaesktop/200

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are happy with the output, then remove the echo (before the mv)

```
 for file in *GAP 
    do 
        NEW_FILE=$(echo ${file} | awk -F. '{print $1,$2,$3,$4,$8,$10,$12}' OFS=.)
        echo mv ${file} ${NEW_FILE}
     done
```

Comment: Many many thanks. It worked perfectly. I just took out the echo before the mv.